# Error on Set range statement

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone please help with this code? It throws an error on the 6th line (`Set rng = Sheet3.Range(Cells(1,i),Cells(1,j)).Select`) but i don't know how to fix it.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 3
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 5
    Set Rng = Sheet3.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, j)).Select
    lAnswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng)
    Sheet1.Cells(5, 13).Value = lAnswer
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) _Which_ error is throwing exactly? 2) What is in the first row, columns 3 and 5 of the Sheet3? 3) Does Sheet3 exist? 4) Can you explain what you're trying to do? The code is very strangely written.

Comment: Hi Matteo yes everything is in sheet3, on the first row I entered values, I am just trying a simple code before I incorporate it to my worksheets. What I am trying to do is sum up let say 5 cells in a particular row then go to the next row then sum up the same cells.    thats why I am trying to see if I can use the cell function for the range that way i can put it in a loop later on and increase i each time

Answer (score 3):

You have received an answer to the syntax issue but I would also caution you about orphaned cell references in the use of the two [Range.Cells properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) used to define the scope of the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). Specifically, their [Range .Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) is arbitrary.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim lAnswer As Double

    i = 3
    j = 5
    with Sheet3
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(1, j))
    end with
    lAnswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng)
    Sheet1.Cells(5, 13).Value = lAnswer

End Sub
```

That one line could also be written as,

```
Set Rng = Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(1, i), Sheet3.Cells(1, j))
```

... but the [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) cleans it up tidily. Without specifying the parent of .Cells, you run the risk of trying to define a range on Sheet3 that includes the cells from another worksheet. I realize that this is a command button and arbitrary cell range parentage *should* implicitly be the worksheet containing the button clicked but you are defining Sheet3 for the .Range so good coding practise dictates that you complete the exercise by explicitly defining Sheet3 as the parent of the nested .Cells.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the 'select' part of that line.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim lAnswer As Long

    i = 3
    j = 5
    Set Rng = Sheet3.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(1, j)) 'remove '.select'
    lAnswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Rng)
    Sheet1.Cells(5, 13).Value = lAnswer

End Sub
```